# Trouble with List (UWP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I writing app for UWP  platform.

I using Binding in code.

Here code for my ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Milano.Annotations;
using WooCommerceNET;
using WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Milano.Classes
{
    public class InWorkViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        private List<LineItem> productList;
        public List<LineItem> ProductList
        {
            get { return productList; }
            set { productList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private List<RootObject> ordersList;

        public List<RootObject> OrdersList
        {
            get { return ordersList; }
            set { ordersList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }


        private RootObject ordersChange;

        public RootObject OrdersChange
        {
            get { return ordersChange; }
            set { ordersChange = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private LineItem ordersChange2;

        public LineItem OrdersChange2
        {
            get { return ordersChange2; }
            set { ordersChange2 = value;OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public  InWorkViewModel()
        {


            Inwork_down();
           // var interval = 100000;
            //UpdateWithImterwal(interval);


        }

        /* private async void UpdateWithImterwal(int interval)
         {


            // OrdersList.Clear();
           Inwork_down();

             await Task.Delay(interval).ContinueWith(_ => UpdateWithImterwal(interval));
         }*/
        public async void Inwork_down()
        {

            RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_9d64c027d2c5f81b8bed3342eeccc6d337be813d", "cs_60697b1e6cbdeb8d62d19e0765e339f8e3334754");
            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
            //Get all products
            var orders = await wc.GetOrders(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                          { "per_page", "100" }, { "status","processing"} }); // Dodelat filtr dlaya teh chto v  rabote


            string products = orders.ToFormattedJsonString();
            Debug.WriteLine(products);


            List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(products);


            OrdersList = new List<RootObject>(rootObjectData);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public class Billing
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string address_1 { get; set; }
        public string address_2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Shipping
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string address_1 { get; set; }
        public string address_2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }

    public class LineItem
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public int product_id { get; set; }
        public int variation_id { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public string tax_class { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public double subtotal { get; set; }
        public double subtotal_tax { get; set; }
        public double total { get; set; }
        public double total_tax { get; set; }
        public List<object> taxes { get; set; }
        public List<object> meta { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShippingLine
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string method_title { get; set; }
        public string method_id { get; set; }
        public double total { get; set; }
        public double total_tax { get; set; }
        public List<object> taxes { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int parent_id { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string order_key { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public bool prices_include_tax { get; set; }
        public string date_created { get; set; }
        public string date_modified { get; set; }
        public int customer_id { get; set; }
        public double discount_total { get; set; }
        public double discount_tax { get; set; }
        public double shipping_total { get; set; }
        public double shipping_tax { get; set; }
        public double cart_tax { get; set; }
        public double total { get; set; }
        public double total_tax { get; set; }
        public Billing billing { get; set; }
        public Shipping shipping { get; set; }
        public string payment_method { get; set; }
        public string payment_method_title { get; set; }
        public string transaction_id { get; set; }
        public string customer_ip_address { get; set; }
        public string customer_user_agent { get; set; }
        public string created_via { get; set; }
        public string customer_note { get; set; }
        public string date_completed { get; set; }
        public string date_paid { get; set; }
        public string cart_hash { get; set; }
        public List<LineItem> line_items { get; set; }
        public List<object> tax_lines { get; set; }
        public List<ShippingLine> shipping_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> fee_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> coupon_lines { get; set; }
    }
```

Where is my problem.

As you see I have this `public List<LineItem> line_items { get; set; }` in classes. I need to take this list from RootObject and make Binding for values in it like I do for rootObject.

So what is logic of View in app. I Binв some data to Left panel, when I tap element on left panel, I make visible right panel, where I bind properties from `public RootObject OrdersChange`.

Here is some screens:

[image: Left List]

[image: Right List]

How I can do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I totally follow this but it sounds like you should look at the Mast/Detail sample form [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want bind 2 classes to one view. If so, I can suggest 2 ways:
1) Create base class for this 2 classes.

```
    class BaseClass { }

class RootObject: BaseClass { }

class LineItem : BaseClass { }

class MainViewModel
{
    public List<LineItem> ProductList { get; set; }
    public List<RootObject> OrdersList { get; set; }

    public BaseClass LeftListViewSelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

2) Or you can set return type of property LeftListViewSelectedItem to object. For binding it's no matter what you return.